# Ajax response return whole page and my php code

Tags: ajax, response

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'parse.php',
    data: {
        g_data: content
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert("ok")
    }
});
```

My php file :

```
<?php

echo "result!!";
```

in response I see all of tags and codes

Comment: If you display directly your php file (parse.php) in your navigator, is it correctly display ?

Comment: no it is not correct
all of my php code in parse.php come in the response with whole tags

Comment: Where is your project ? In you local computer or server ? Do you even install a HTTP server with PHP like nginx or apache  ?